# Validation input box and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I want validate this tab content  with jQuery, I want validate only second div  with `id='lang2'`. How can I do this?

```html
<div class="tab-content ">
<div id="lang1" class="tab-pane  ">
   <div class="col s12">
      <div class="form-group  " id="lang_name">
         <input class="form-control contact-method" placeholder="Enter property name" name="name[1]" type="text">
         <label for="name[1]">Property name</label>                                                                                
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12">
      <textarea class="hidden desc-content contact-method" name="description[1]" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label for="require" class="error-input"> Please enter your description* </label>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="lang2" class="tab-pane active ">
<div class="col s12">
   <div class="form-group  " id="lang_name">
      <input class="form-control contact-method" placeholder="Enter property name" name="name[2]" type="text">
      <label for="name[2]">Property name</label>
      <textarea class="hidden desc-content contact-method" name="description[1]" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>                                                                     
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which fields in tab2 you want to validate? only input you want to check empty or not?

Comment: I want validate the input text and text area(summernote) the two required only in second tab .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will works for you.

```
$('#submit').on(click, function () { 


        $('#lang2').find("input[type=text],textarea").each(function (e)
        {

                if ($(this).val().trim() === "")
                {
                   Alert('Please Enter Value')
                   return false;    
                 }
                }

        });
```

Comment: in my case lang2 is id="lang{{$language->id}}"  but I put lang2 for more simplify so  I c'ant use it $().

Comment: it means you can't get it by id then get it by name add name attribute to div and give it a name and get it by the following way $('[name="yourdiv"]')

Comment: the same think I have  name="name['.$language->id.']"

Comment: why are you using name['.$language->id.'] this ? what is for. Then give your div a class name and do it by getting your class name.

Comment: If you language id is 2 like lang2 then add your class at your comparison clause and your function will work

Comment: thanks for your time  I resolve the problem by other way.